# Why would Java compiler require a return value?

Tags: java

```
public MyObject method1() {
  boolean someBoolean = true;
  MyObject obj = ...;

  if(!someBoolean) method1();
  else return obj;
  // flow should never come to this statement, but compiler requires this return. why?
  return null;
}
```

why does the java compiler require the final return statement?

-Prasanna

Comment: Because you've defined in the signature of the method that their should be a return type MyObject. Plus all paths in the method have to have a return if its not void.

Comment: You are mistaken. Control can indeed get to the point you indicate. Not a real question.

Comment: Should've posted my comment as an answer haha.

Comment: My bad. It makes sense to be if(!someBoolean) return method1()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `!someBoolean`, then `method1` is called, but nothing is returned.  So flow totally could end up at that last statement.

Answer (score 4):

Because if your boolean is not true you aren't returning anything. Java requires all methods to return their corresponding value type (in this case, `MyObject`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your code:

```
public MyObject method1() {
  boolean someBoolean = true;
  MyObject obj = ...;

  if(!someBoolean) return method1();
  else return obj;
}
```

Originally, your if statement didn't return anything if `!someBoolean`, it just called `method1()` and ignored the result.